# What's the life before EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am reading a book on EJB. It list one advantage over the older techniques of EJB is that it free programmers from one specific application server vendor and its properietary APIs.

I am wondering what was the life before EJB came out? Which specific application server did programmer use in the old days? Could you give me a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1997-8, there were numerous application server products on the market.  EJB and its cousins (JSP, Servlet, JDBC, JCA, etc) attempted to standardize the metaphor for programming server-side Java applications.

Some of the app servers on the market at that time were:

- NetDynamics - I think their product was called Spider or something
- Kiva App Server
- Netscape iPlanet
- IBM Websphere
- Lotus Domino
- Sybase Jaguar
- WebLogic Tengah
- Secant
- Forte
- Oracle App Server - was independent of WebLogic in those days
- Haht
- SilverStream
- Caucho Resin
- Bluestone
- Allaire
- Novera
- Jonas

There were many others.

These app server products were, in a practical sense, *defining* the server-side app platform. They were inventing the metaphor of object-based server-side programming in Java.  How to map an HTTP Session to a Java object?  How to handle HTTP Authentication?  How to handle administration?  Each server-side product did it differently.

Many of these companies were small, and the half-life of the companies was short, maybe 12 months or so.  At one point the people involved in WebLogic looked at the field and decided that there was too much variety; that Microsoft would be able to defeat each of them independently and thus "win" the server-side app platform battle. So they decided to band together and define a common API, to achieve a stronger competitive position with respect to Microsoft. This was the birth of J2EE.  The ostensible benefit for customers was server-side platform portability.

In those days app server companies were tiny, so a good deal of risk was associated to committing to a particular app server API. standardized APIs like Servlet, JSP, and EJB diminished some of that risk, and it made it easier for a particular company to choose, let's say, NetDynamics, knowing that if NetD went under, they'd be able to move their programs to WebLogic fairly easily.  Platform portability was a big win for potential customers.

Comment: Kudos for sharing the story with us :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let me contribute one.

1. Manage your own transaction, i.e. all the things to do together to roll back when one unit of a transaction fails.

This is handled by EJB, CMP or BMP.

Comment: Is there any example with source code about that? I am newbie on Java enterprise level develop. I have only used transaction for once in a small php project.

Comment: You need to 1. insert into address table, 2. insert into customer table, 3. update employee table. If unit 3 fails, do you need to roll back the changes made to 1 and 2? Yes, how? With EJB - You can choose CMP or BMP. Without EJB - You need to write codes to roll back.

Comment: So you mean with EJB, we do not need to write code like this:http://snipt.org/tomk9

Comment: Careful!  You need EJB transactions only for operations that involve more than one transactional resource.  If all of the tables  that get updated are managed by the same database, let's say, Oracle, then you don't need an external transaction, such as provided by EJB.  If you want to update Oracle and Sybase as part of one unit of work, you need an external transaction, and EJB can provide that. Most people do not need the transactional part of EJB.

Comment: @Cheeso: Do you mean in the transaction as Chin Boon said, we do not need EJB to manage transaction. Only if the tables of transaction have copies in other database, that is, synchronized with other database do we need EJB...?

Comment: @Jichao - what I mean is, EJB *can* be used to manage transactions at a single resource manager (aka database), or it can be used to manage transactions that span resources managers (multiple databases). But, if you have only one database, you can use database-specific transactions, such as you showed at your snipt link. BTW, I don't know what you mean by "if the tables of transaction have copies in other database."  I am not talking about copies of tables.  What I am saying is EJB can manage transactions where the updated tables reside in different databases.

Comment: I mean, a table(e.g called Order) reside in two databases, but they are syncrhonized, that is if you update Order in database 1, then you should upate Order in the database 2. And Do you mean, a transation with one update on table A and another update on table B, but the two tables are reside in different databases?

Comment: @Cheeso - I think that the EJB Transactions might be useful not only when you use 2 databases, but generally 2 different JCA resources, right? Or i.e. If I want to read the message from JMS and do some database changes - all in one transaction. I could use the transactionality to be sure that if something fails I want the JMS message not to be set as 'delivered' and the database changes to be rolled-back.

Comment: @Piotr - yes, that's correct.  2 different transactional resources, or in J2EE parlance, "JCA resources".   In the most common case that would mean 2 different databases, but it could also mean a message queue and a database.  a common scenario is retrieving a message from a message queue, then updating a database.  This might be a thing you'd want to do transactionally, as you said.  In fact this scenario was *so common* that a later revision of the EJB spec defined a new EJB type to cover it - the MDB or Message Driven Bean.

Comment: @Jichao - yes. The case where you have a table in two databases, and you want the databases to contain exact copies, is one special case of the situation I described - in which an application updates two distinct transactional resources, as part of one unit of work.  I think that typically, using distributed transactions is probably not the best way of maintaining a copy of a table on a remote database. For example there are offline synchronization mechanisms that do this in batches. But I don't know your requirements; you may have a scenario that works best with distributed transactions.